# how to install nasm on mingw for build openh264 library for windows application using pjsip library

Tags: c++, gcc, nasm, pjsip, openh264

I am struggling with build openh264 library in mingw . showing some error like nasm not INSTALLED ERROR found ..How to resolve the issues..

actually i want to add video settings in pjsip library for running call applications..
I have put command in mingw like >>make install .

Anyone know the issues or correct command to  build the library.

Any help.thanks in advance...

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows#BuildPreparationforWindows
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1947

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, and I had to install NASM on MinGW. The latest version of NASM wouldn't install for me, so I used this version:
https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12.03rc1/

I copied nasm-2.12.03rc1.zip and unzipped it to /MinGW/msys/1.0/nasm-2.12.03rc1/ from Windows Explorer, then I installed it using the steps here:
https://github.com/letolabs/nasm/blob/master/INSTALL

Within the MinGW shell, I then ran "cd /openh264-master/" and "make" to install OpenH264.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Donald.Lets try.i have to check it .